# node.js | knex: command not found

Tags: knex.js

I installed node.js on my shared hosting with Cpanel ([See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWuIB.jpg))

Then knex installed without any problem.

```json
{
  "name": "cmonapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "APPLICATION NAME",
  "main": "start.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Meric",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "hapi-auth-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.2",
    "knex": "^0.14.6",
    "mysql": "^2.15.0"
  }
}
```

But when I try to run knex init command by the SSH I get an error like " -bash: knex: command not found "

Can someone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: duplicate of [How to use the Knex CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50487234/how-to-use-the-knex-cli)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I solved the problem. In .bashrc file specified alias like "alias knex=/home/USER/nodevenv/APP/8/lib/node_modules/knex/bin/cli.js"

Now I can use all the knex commands.

Answer (score 33):

`knex` binary will be installed in the `node_modules/.bin` folder.

If you are using `npm@5.2.0` and above, use `npx` to access your local dependencies like:

```
➜ npx knex --version

Knex CLI version:  0.15.0
Local Knex version:  0.15.0
```

If `npx` is not available,

```
➜ $(npm bin)/knex --version

Knex CLI version:  0.15.0
Local Knex version:  0.15.0
```

Needless to say `knex init` command would work in both the options

```
➜ npx knex init

Created ./knexfile.js
```

Answer (score 26):

either install knex globally

`npm install -g knex`

or

use `npx knex`
this will read to your node_modules directory and run the bin/knex executable.

Answer (score 4):

You installed it locally to your NodeJS project.

Sou you can `const knex = require('knex')`.
But you can't `knex -v`.

To install it globally run `npm i -g knex`